# pip reporting dependency conflict when adding optional dependencies consisting of type stubs

Tags: python, pip, pyproject.toml

I'm using pyproject.toml to manage my install.  Installing the application works as expected.  However when I try to install the specified `dev` dependencies, pip reports a conflict with a message that seems difficult to resolve:

```
The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested tnc-py 0.3.6 (from ...app-py)
    app-py[dev] 0.3.6 depends on app-py 0.3.6 (Installed) <<< ??
```

The pyproject.toml snippets

```ini
[project]
name = "app-py"
version = "0.3.6"
requires-python = ">=3.10"

dependencies = [
    "boto3",
    "flask",
    "flask-cors",
    "flask-redis",
    "flask-session2",
    "numpy",
    "pandas"
]

[project.optional-dependencies]
dev = [
    "types-flask",
    "pandas-stubs",
    "boto3-stubs"
]
```

```
> pip3 install app-py[dev] .
The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested app-py 0.3.6 (from ../app-py)
    app-py[dev] 0.3.6 depends on app-py 0.3.6 (Installed)

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

If there is a more idiomatic way to go about what I'm trying to do, please let me know.  Otherwise, explain my misunderstanding of how to accomplish the task.  Thank you.